# How can I store the output of a query into a temporary table and use the table in a new query?

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I have a MySQL query which uses 3 tables with 2 inner joins. Then, I have to find the maximum of a group from this query output. Combining them both is beyond me. Can I break down the problem by storing the output of the first complicated query into some sort of temporary table, give it a name and then use this table in a new query? This will make the code more manageable. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `CREATE TEMP TABLE`?

Comment: you can do all this in one query submit what you have tried so far. if you want to make temporary tables you can but 2 inner joins is not that much to require a temp table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very straightforward:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempname  AS (    
    SELECT whatever, whatever
      FROM rawtable
      JOIN othertable ON this = that
)
```

The temporary table will vanish when your connection closes. A temp table contains the data that was captured at the time it was created.

You can also create a view, like so.

```
CREATE VIEW viewname AS (    
    SELECT whatever, whatever
      FROM rawtable
      JOIN othertable ON this = that
)
```

Views are permanent objects (they don't vanish when your connection closes) but they retrieve data from the underlying tables at the time you invoke them.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, do you recommend using mysql temporary tables in a situation like this ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45164132/why-i-cant-use-the-name-of-the-derived-tablesubquery-result-again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45164132/why-i-cant-use-the-name-of-the-derived-tablesubquery-result-again)) ?

Comment: @Accountant In short, no. In generic MySQL, temp tables are close to useless because of their restrictions.  MariaDB 10.2 (a MySQL fork) has common table expressions, which are the good way to solve that problem.  Or, use a view to avoid typing the subquery twice.