# Why I can't use the name of the derived table(subquery result) again?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to reuse the table resulting from a sub-query, But when I try to execute a SQL like this one

```
SELECT id 
FROM company
LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT * FROM sales
    -- join
    -- join
    -- join
    -- join
    ) foo
ON foo.company_id = company.id

LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT company_id,balance FROM foo -- generates error
    UNION ALL
    SELECT company_id,balance FROM manual_moves
    ) moves
ON moves.company_id = company.id;
-- note: the actual sub-query has been omitted to make it focused on the error
```

unfortunately I'm getting an Error

> Table 'databaseName.foo' doesn't exist

The sub-query that build the `foo` table has lots of joins and I don't want to re write the **same** sub-query again *(I guess this will have an impact on performance)*

**Is there a way I can reuse the name of that sub-query result table -foo- again ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump the content of your "foo" query into a temp table first, then query that temp table in your main query.

Comment: thank you for your helpful replay. do you mean something like this ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260257/how-can-i-store-the-output-of-a-query-into-a-temporary-table-and-use-the-table-i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260257/how-can-i-store-the-output-of-a-query-into-a-temporary-table-and-use-the-table-i)) ?

Comment: Exactly. I'm a SQL Server guy, so I can't comment on the exact syntax for MySQL, but that looks about right.

Comment: I'm sorry the temp table solution does not work in my situation  because mysql stated that **"You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query"** [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/temporary-table-problems.html) . I'm getting an "Can't reopen table"  error

Comment: Ouch! No such limitations in SQL Server. Are multiple instances of your query likely to run in parallel? If not you could create a physical table (lose the TEMPORARY keyword), dump the contents in there and DROP it after extracting your results.

Comment: See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f84454/3 for an example (you'll need to uncomment the DROP TABLE line in your code)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort in the sqlfiddle. I'm also thinking of using a view.